# dynamic object, with If statement, how to improve this function

Tags: .net, c#-4.0

```
    public dynamic obj1( dynamic obj2)
    {
         if (obj2.GetType() == typeof(Obj3)
          {
            //do something
          }

         if (obj2.GetType() == typeof(Obj4)
          {
            //do something else
          }

         if (obj2.GetType() == typeof(Obj5)
          {
            //do something else
          }

            //return something
    }
```

is there a way i can improve this? I to compare to about 70 different objects, I can't use reflection..I don't know how else I can improve this.

The caller of this function will be passing in the right type(not dynamic), but it returns a dynamic, i don't relly know where to start with this one

Comment: Since obj2 can only be of one type use if/elseifs instead of an array of ifs. This way you will not do any of the proceeding if checks if your statement is true. 

This can also be done via a select statement.

Comment: If you can change the classes themselves (Obj-n) then put a common interface on them with a method that will contain the code block for the one in question. Since you are using `dynamic` C# will dispatch to the correct implementation.

Comment: @Frank J can you write what you mean? I'm not too sure i am following you

Comment: I added an answer, but it might not be feasible in your case, but is an alternate approach.

Comment: It is an `object`, unless you need `dynamic` why even bother returning it all?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could do something with first class functions which is definitely how I would do it in something like javascript.

But, even in c#, the functional approach is lower in ceremony,  more testable, and removes most of the boilerplate. The object oriented alternatives seem to me to just muddy the waters with regards to intent:

Here is a simplified example with lambdas:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
class MainClass {
  public static void Main (string[] args) {

    var contents = new Dictionary<System.Type, Func<dynamic, string>>
        {
            {typeof(int), o => "is int"},
            {typeof(string), o => "is string"}
        };

    Func<dynamic, string> worker = o => contents[o.GetType()](o);   

    Console.WriteLine(worker(1));
    Console.WriteLine(worker("foo"));
  }
}
```

You can run it here:
https://repl.it/CGJO/4

You put a function on the dictionary for every type you want to handle.  Of course, if the functions are long, then you wouldn't use lambdas,  You'd declare them like this:

```
Func<dynamic, string> intFunc = delegate(dynamic o)
     { return "Is integer";}; 
Func<dynamic, string> stringFunc = delegate(dynamic o)
     { return "Is string";}; 

var contents = new Dictionary<System.Type, Func<dynamic, string>>
    {
        {typeof(int), intFunc}, {typeof(string), stringFunc}
    };
```

https://repl.it/CGJO/8

Comment: var contents = new Dictionary<System.Type, Func<dynamic, string>>
        {
            {typeof(int), o => RunFuctionA();},
        };  how can i do something like this?

Answer (score 2):

If you can change the various `Obj` you could create an interface:

```
public interface IObjectHandler
{
     void Dispatch();
}
```

Obviously change the signature to what you need it to be.

Now put that interface on all of you objects and implement in the `Dispatch` method the code that pertains to each one.

Last but not least you can call it this way:

```
public dynamic obj1( dynamic obj2)
{
     IObjectHandler tmp = obj2 as IObjectHandler;
     if(tmp != null)
        tmp.Dispatch();
}
```

Now this doesn't really make use of the fact that you use `dynamic`. As a matter of fact you can even change in this case your signature to:

```
public IObjectHandler obj1( IObjectHandler obj2)
```

This obviously only works with classes that you created, but since you didn't give more info, this is an alternative approach.

If this needs to work for stuff like `int`, `string` or whatever, this will not work at all.

Now if you objects are all in an inheritance hierarchy that opens different options up for you. You can just implement the method in the base class and then override as needed.

Answer (score 1):

> is there a way i can improve this?

Create an overload for each type.  The amount of code won;t be much different that having 70 different `if` statements, and you have compile-time type safety.

You don't say how different the code is for each type, but hopefully there are some base classes or something that you can reduce the number of functions.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to overload or make a interface, you could use the good old `switch case` or even use `else if` statements.

Comment: I didn't think switch works with types, is that new in C# 6?